# How do I use window functions ("over") together with crosstab in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

## Table: application_app

```
         applied_date          | applied_class | id
-------------------------------+---------------+-----
 2013-03-06 15:59:49.22774-05  | BOSFAL13      |  13
 2013-05-12 16:56:34.749859-04 | BOSFAL13      | 232
 2013-05-26 15:48:11.969723-04 | BOSFAL13      | 359
 2013-06-02 23:02:17.267199-04 | BOSFAL13      | 400
 2013-06-03 12:35:46.90801-04  | BOSFAL13      | 408
 2013-06-08 19:17:42.179707-04 | NYCFAL13      | 449
 2013-06-11 02:04:38.232501-04 | NYCFAL13      | 450
 2013-06-11 13:05:42.509843-04 | NYCFAL13      | 452
 2013-06-12 09:19:21.459897-04 | BOSFAL13      | 454
 2013-06-13 02:38:52.782411-04 | NYCFAL13      | 456
 2013-06-17 19:41:31.813795-04 | NYCFAL13      | 457
 2013-06-18 17:39:04.892315-04 | BOSFAL13      | 459
 2013-06-19 09:05:29.892635-04 | BOSFAL13      | 460
 2013-06-21 09:06:06.380306-04 | NYCFAL13      | 462
 2013-06-22 05:02:31.699312-04 | BOSFAL13      | 463
```

I'm trying to use `crosstab` to get an aggregate of applied_class over time (by day).

## Current Query

```
select *

from crosstab(
    'select temp_table.d,  
       applied_class,  
       sum(temp_table.ct) over (order by d) 

    from   
       (
        select count(id) ct, 
               applied_class, 
               to_char(date_trunc($$day$$, applied_date), $$MM-DD$$) d from application_app 
        where applied_class like $$%L13$$ 
        group by applied_class, d 
        order by d
        ) as temp_table
    order by 1, 2'

    ,'VALUES ($$BOSFAL13$$::text), ($$NYCFAL13$$::text), ($$CHIFAL13$$::text), ($$MULTIPLECITIESFALL13$$::text)')  -- end crosstab

as ct ("Day" text, "Boston" int, "New York" int, "Chicago" int, "Any City" int);
```

This query is very close, but it's increasing the count for *each* `applied_class` whenever there is a record for *any* `applied_class`:

## Results

```
  Day  | Boston | New York | Chicago | Any Class
-------+--------+----------+---------+-----------
 03-06 |      1 |          |         |
 05-12 |      2 |          |         |
 05-26 |      3 |          |         |
 06-02 |      4 |          |         |
 06-03 |      6 |          |         |
 06-08 |        |        7 | <-- First "New York" record, but adds prev 6 from "Boston"
 06-11 |        |       11 |         |
 06-12 |     12 |          |         |
 06-13 |        |       13 |         |
 06-17 |        |       14 |         |
 06-18 |     16 |          |         |
 06-19 |     18 |          |         |
 06-21 |        |       19 |         |
```

How can I change this query so that it aggregates the `applied_class` records by city, instead of adding the previous records from all cities?

Comment: I think your query is too complex; I don't understand the need to have the inner `group by` as the outer `sum() over()` should work without it (ignoring reformatting of data for the moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `partition` clause to the `over()`:

I would expect

```
sum(ct) over (partition by applied_class order by d)
```

to do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what [Colin already cleared up](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51113/3684):

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$SELECT (applied_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')::date AS d
         ,applied_class
         ,sum(count(id)) OVER (PARTITION BY applied_class
                         ORDER BY (applied_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')::date)
   FROM   application_app
   WHERE  applied_class LIKE '%L13'
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2$$

  ,$$VALUES ('BOSFAL13'::text), ('NYCFAL13'), ('CHIFAL13'), ('MULTIPLECITIESFALL13')$$)

AS ct ("Day" date, "Boston" int, "New York" int, "Chicago" int, "Any City" int);
```

#### Major points

- The extracted day depends on the time zone setting of the current session. Your sample displays `timestamp with time zone` literals, which indicates you may be operating in multiple distinct time zones. To get the date for a particular time zone, you have to *declare* that, or the current setting will be applied - which is easily overlooked and therefore a **loaded footgun**: You would get different numbers, depending on *where* you run the query!
  Details:

  - [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)
  - [Accounting for DST in Postgres, when selecting scheduled items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243029/939860)

  Safe syntax would be:

  ```sql
  to_char(applied_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'MM-DD')  -- your time zone
  ```
- There is **another trap**. If you `GROUP BY` day and month only, you can easily aggregate dates from multiple years by accident. I use the *full* date in my example.
  Plus, skipping the key word `AS` is fine for *table* aliases but not for *column* aliases. So:

  ```sql
  (applied_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')::date AS d
  ```

  See:

  - [SELECT Query merge / join two tables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861401/939860)
- You don't need `date_trunc()` here. `to_char()` can work with the original timestamp directly.

  ```sql
  to_char(applied_date, 'MM-DD')
  ```
- You do not *need* a subquery. Window functions can be computed `OVER` aggregate functions. `sum(count(id)) OVER ...` in my query. More explanation in this related answer on SO:

  - [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169627/939860)

  You'd have to test which is faster. I don't expect much of a difference.
- It's more efficient to invert your use of dollar-quotes and plain quotes.
- It's sufficient to declare the type in the first row of a `VALUES` expression.

Comment: Wow.  So valuable.  Thanks for taking the time to expand my knowledge.