# Sum duration for each day of a month

Tags: postgresql, functions, timestamp

Question: I would like to create a query that can return a list of all days of the month with a sum of all duration for each day including zero for each day that has no data.

Database: PostgreSQL 9.x

Table structure (only relevant columns shown):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id | start_at            | finish_at           | duration |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2015-08-14 14:01:00 | 2015-08-15 13:59:00 | 86280    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the following query for grabbing the data I want but the part that is missing is the days between with zero and I'm not entirely sure on the best approach to achieve the desired outcome.

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', start_at) AS "day" , sum(duration) AS "duration"
FROM time_logs
JOIN users ON time_logs.user_id = users.id
JOIN account_users ON account_users.user_id = users.id
JOIN categories ON categories.id = time_logs.activity_id
WHERE account_users.account_id IN (1,2,3)
AND time_logs.start_at BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00 +1000' AND '2017-03-31 00:00:00 +1000'
AND categories.report_group = 'Segment1'
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: take a look at this [answer for generating a sequence of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113580/7366100); you should be able to use said series to perform: `date_series` left join `current_query`, converting any `sum(duration)=NULL` to zero; if you still can't get it working then post back with an updated version of your working sql ... it shouldn't take much tweaking to get it to work

Comment: BTW, "PostgreSQL 9.x" does not say much. See: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think the comment meant the OP's **own** SQL and not the server version!

Answer (score 2):

Add an [outer join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) to a complete series of days using [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES):

```
SELECT day, COALESCE(duration, 0) AS duration
FROM  (  -- your original query, just added table aliases to reduce noise
         -- and fixed the upper bound of your time range
   SELECT date_trunc('day', t.start_at) AS day
        , sum(duration) AS duration  -- add table qualification to duration
   FROM   time_logs     t
   JOIN   users         u  ON t.user_id = u.id
   JOIN   account_users a  ON a.user_id = u.id
   JOIN   categories    c  ON c.id = t.activity_id
   WHERE  a.account_id IN (1,2,3)
   AND    t.start_at >='2017-03-01 00:00 +1'
   AND    t.start_at < '2017-04-01 00:00 +1' -- to get the whole month
   AND    c.report_group = 'Segment1'
   GROUP  BY 1 
   ) sub
RIGHT  JOIN generate_series(timestamptz '2017-03-01 00:00 +1'
                                      , '2017-03-31 00:00 +1'  -- !
                                      , '1 day') day USING (day)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

And [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to get 0 ("zero") instead of NULL, if you need that.

`BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00 +1' AND '2017-03-31 00:00 +1'` would exclude the last day of march (except for its very first µs). I changed it to include the *whole* month. `AND t.start_at < '2017-04-01 00:00 +1'` has the additional advantage that you don't need to adapt the day of the upper bound, just the month.

Since `start_at` is obviously `timestamptz`, that's the most efficient call with matching data type. Detailed explanation here:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/14113580#14113580)

The actual data type of `start_at` and your actual time zone setting might lead to disagreement *when* days start. Consider:

- [How do I use window functions ("over") together with crosstab in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51103/how-do-i-use-window-functions-over-together-with-crosstab-in-postgres/51175#51175)
- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: +1 - exactly what I was grasping for. I did have it done with CTEs, but I just couldn't get it over the finishing line!

Comment: @Vérace: Yes, a CTE would be another option. Typically a bit more expensive than a subquery in Postgres since the derived table is materialized. That's why I favor subqueries where possible.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks this has helped a lot, still learning a lot as Ruby on Rails has abstracted this away for many years since doing MSSQL... Just stuck on something your RIGHT join returns all zeros and changing to a LEFT join only returns days with data. What am I missing?

Comment: @DanielDraper: `generate_series()` as *first* `FROM` item, followed by a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to your subquery would be equivalent. All zeroes?  `date_trunc()` necessarily understands "days" according to the current time zone setting. Your question shows `timestamp` and `timestamptz` literals. *Every* question like this should start with an exact table definition showing data types and constraints: `CREATE TABLE ...`, and your exact version of Postgres (like I hinted already). I added some more info to the answer.